# Exporting a Microsoft report to PDF doesn't show Chinese characters

Tags: c#, report, chinese-locale

I've got the problem that I get no Chinese characters when exporting a Microsoft Report to a PDF file.

```
byte[] mybytes = report.Render("pdf");
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"D:\output.pdf"))
{
    fs.Write(mybytes, 0, mybytes.Length);
}
```

If I export the same report to a Word file it works fine.

```
byte[] myWordbytes = report.Render("word");
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"D:\output.doc"))
{
    fs.Write(myWordbytes, 0, myWordbytes.Length);
}
```

When converting that Word file to PDF, I also get the Chinese characters in the converted PDF file.

I don't want to do this workaround. How can I solve this?

The required fonts seem to be embedded into the PDF.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFH2f.png)

Comment: You say you "get no Chinese characters". What _do_ you get instead? Are they stripped out, or are they garbled?

Comment: I get this here: 

Comment: That may just be an issue where the required fonts don't get embedded into the PDF.